# Rails metamask authentification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I wan't to create an api which users can signup using web3 signature for signup/signin
Is devise offering such feature ?
Or in more general way disable password for devise user model and costumise login verification to check if signature and token are valid

Answer (score 0):

web3 providers do not provide a server-side API for authorization & authentication normally.

but you can ask users to [sign a specified string](https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/blob/d46d922e2d9714b6e8bd72db665f708f12e222ea/docs/web3-eth-personal.rst#sign), for example `sign in MyWebSite, timestamp 1606824023`, then [check the signature and recover the public key](https://github.com/se3000/ruby-eth/issues/18#issuecomment-925018838) on server-side.

Comment: yes i was able to make it with custom functions , but i want to integrate it with devise token auth

Comment: @SamiFakhfakh sorry but I'm not familiar with devise token auth. If devise token auth allows you write your own codes to handle a `token`, you can just send the signature as the `token`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found, add this strategy to devise

```
require 'devise/strategies/authenticatable'

module Devise
  module Strategies
    class DeviseNoPass < Authenticatable
      def authenticate!
        return super unless params[:address]
        user = User.find_by_address(params[:address]) if validate_signature(params[:address], params[:token], params[:signature])
        user ? success!(user) : raise
      end

      def validate_signature(address, token, signature)
        # signer information
        signer_address = address
        # message and signatre (from javascript/metamask)
        message = token
        signature = signature #"0x03a45db0ec6cada40f0227bb67cfd99e69a92c5c6809450d4db884c83b41401c062c039f1465012965ec2426c0dd2d4d3737cf08009866f9a3bccfa3f312bda81c"
        # recover the public key from the signature
        recovered_public_key = Eth::Key.personal_recover message, signature
        # recover the address from the public key
        recovered_address = Eth::Utils.public_key_to_address recovered_public_key
        signer_address.eql? recovered_address
      end


    end
  end
end

Warden::Strategies.add(:devise_no_pass, Devise::Strategies::DeviseNoPass)
```